# Set up default TestNG launch configuration in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

I'm running quite a few TestNG tests in Eclipse, but for each one, I need to pass in the same VM arguments. Is there any way to set this to be default, so I don't have to enter it each time I write a new test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that is quite problemmatic, probably the easiest workaround is to set them globally (*Preferences -> TestNG -> Run/Debug -> JVM args*).

Otherwise, if you create a run configuration for the test package, you can also set it there.

Comment: Is this still possible with the latest TestNG plugin (6.9.11.201604020423) and Eclipse Mars 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the arguments globally:
Window > Preferences >TestNG > Run/Debug

If you have more than one argument, seperate them with blanks.