# Allure AShot() screenshots in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot, allure, yandex

Im experimenting with Allure aShot() class to take screenshots of specific WebElements on a website I'm working on, and below is the code I used in selenium to make it happen. 
Please visit this link, which shows aShot() project documentation:

https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot

So My QUESTION is that, where are these AShot() screenshots of the WebElement actually being saved? I used testNG to execute below method and successfully able to generate allure reports but I can't see these screenshots in those reports or anywhere in my framework. Please check below code, it is very difficult to pinpoint the location of these images.

So again, my basic question is: How do we specify selenium to store these AShot() screenshots of the WebElement into a particular file that we want?

I've tried to cast Screenshot class mentioned below to BufferedImage or TakesScreenshot class and use ImageIO.write or FileUtils.copyFile methods to copy these images into a file and store these images there, but I get an error saying, for example, "java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot" and I've tried other methods as well, unsuccessfully.

Please help me resolve this issue, how do we know/specify where these AShot() screenshots are being saved?

```
public WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void getAShotImage() {
  driver.get("http://....../");
  WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.xpath(".............."));
  AShot shot = new AShot();
  shot.takeScreenShot(driver, element);

  OR

  shot.coordsProvider(new WebDriverCoordsProvider()).takeScreenshot(driver, element);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your screenshots by returning byte array from the method. Look at the following example:-

```
@Attachment(value="Screenshot", type="image/png")
private static byte[] captureScreenshot(Webdriver driver)
{
    byte[] screenshot = null;
            screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        }
  return screenshot
}
```

Above code does not use Ashot but it shows how you need to attach files. Also, if you are still not able to see your screenshots, check if your steps are displayed in your report.If not then probably you are missing javaagent as discussed in [FAQ](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/FAQ-and-Troubleshooting#xml-files-created-but-no-steps-attachments-or-parameters-are-present-mainly-a-java-issue)

Comment: Hi, I already specified javaagent in my POM file before, but it still doesn't show attachments or parameters in my allure reports. I followed all the steps mentioned in FAQ's link you alluded me to, and I did it all over again by specifying javaagent, but it still doesn't help in displaying attachments/parameters/steps. I can only see features and stories, however, in the allure reports.

Comment: If steps are not there then definitely problem lies with the javaagent. How are you running your test cases?

Comment: Running them through testNG annotations in Maven Project, I tried project compiler compliance level on both 1.5 and 1.7 if that meant anything.

Comment: Please use mvn test as described in the examples. If you have to run using testng eclipse plugin then go to window>preferences>testng>run debug> add -javaagent:{path to your aspect weaver jar}

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help so far. It still didn't work, however. I executed tests through both maven and also set the aspectjweaver path in eclipse as well. Neither of these attachments/parameters/steps show up in allure reports. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, i've been working on this issue for three days now :(

Comment: You can download testng maven example from their repository and check if it works

Comment: Yes, I have done that before. I imported the allure-testng-example project from Github through Eclipse-EGit plugin and cloned the entire project onto my eclipse, then converted it to maven project. But when I execute the program through maven/testNG, it again only shows feature/stories annotations in allure reports, but not other annotations.

Comment: Hi, I was able to finally get the annotations display in allure reports by executing through maven, but with testNG execution the annotations (@Step,@Attachment,@parameters) are not showing at all. And I need to execute all my tests through testNG only. I would greatly appreciate if you can let me know your thoughts on this issue.

Comment: Strangely, it works now after I double quoted javaagent aspectjweaver path in POM file.

Answer (score 0):

AShot returns the `Screenshot` object, that contains the image of your element and information for comparison of screenshots. In this case you can use `getImage()` method to get the image.

```
new AShot().takeScreenshot(....).getImage();
```

The `Screenshot` will contain the byte array instead of `BufferedImage` soon.

Comment: Hi, I was able to finally get the annotations display in allure reports by executing through maven, but with testNG execution the annotations (@Step,@Attachment,@parameters) are not showing at all. And I need to execute all my tests through testNG only. I would greatly appreciate if you can let me know your thoughts on this issue.

Comment: @Manoj these annotations require aspectJ. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: You should specify JVM argLine with aspectJ agent like in maven-surefire-plugin in your pom.xml for build configuration.

Comment: As I know latest idea should use your surefire maven plugin configuration (if I wrong you anyway can use VM options in build configuration), for eclipse you can see the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757803/set-up-default-testng-launch-configuration-in-eclipse

Comment: Yes I have done that before, but it works now after I double quoted javaagent aspectjweaver path in POM file. Thanks for the help.